# How can I configure Sublime Text 3 to select IP addresses by double-clicking them. OS X Yosemite

Tags: osx-yosemite, sublime-text-3

In OS X many (most) text-handling applications can select an IP address by double clicking on them. I work with IP addresses all the time.

I've recently moved away from TextEdit, Notes, and TextWrangler for Sublime 3. In all of those and more you can select an IP address by double clicking on it.

I've tinkered with changing the "word_separators" preference, but can't seem to save even the "default" from https://scotch.io/bar-talk/the-complete-visual-guide-to-sublime-text-3-themes-color-schemes-and-cool-features

Might not be limited to sublime-text-3 and osx-yosemite tags.